# Unexpected character json error in r

Tags: json, r

I'm getting the following error message for this code intended to read Instagram posts into r.  Other code is successfully reading in the first 20 posts, but Instagram wants you to request the "next_url" to get additional blocks of posts.  I looked at similar answers to this error, but can't find the typo in my code.  Did wonder if it could be something coming from the API that needs to be adjusted.  I'm new to R and hope I explained this appropriately.  I would greatly appreciate any assistance.

> ```
> Error in fromJSON(getURL(paste(next_url, token, sep = "")), unexpected.escape = "keep") : 
>   unexpected character: p
> In addition: Warning message:
> In fromJSON(getURL(paste(next_url, token, sep = "")), unexpected.escape = "keep") :
>   unexpected escaped character '\ ' at pos 26. Keeping value.
> ```

```
  username <- "XXXX"
    if(grepl(received_profile$username,username))
  {
    user_id <- received_profile$id
    media <- fromJSON(getURL(paste(next_url,token,sep="")),unexpected.escape = "keep")
    df1 = data.frame(no = 1:length(media$data))

    for(i in 1:length(media$data))
    {
      #comments
      df1$comments[i] <-media$data[[i]]$comments$count

      #likes:
      df1$likes[i] <- media$data[[i]]$likes$count

      #date
      df1$date[i] <- toString(as.POSIXct(as.numeric(media$data[[i]]$created_time), origin="1970-01-01"))
    }
    df <- rbind(df, df1)    
  }else
  {
    print("Error: User not found!")
  }
```

Comment: can you give an example of next url in the question

Comment: here you go.  let me know if you need more info: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/182558180/media/recent?access_token=396503461.fd0ef9f.d867616a398c4fd88f6e14d2cfbf1e6d&max_id=1066000499384366401_182558180"

Comment: one thing that can help for sure here is..if you can hit the same url in your browser and copy the json that you receive in the question itself. It will make it easy to debug.

Answer (score 11):

I can reproduce your problem by extending your code snippet with code that extracts `next_url` from the `pagination` object in the JSON response returned by Instagram.

When using `rjson::fromJSON` to parse the JSON response I get errors like

```
Error in rjson::fromJSON(js) : unexpected character: i
```

However, using `RJSONIO::fromJSON` for parsing the exact same string works just fine! Also the string validates as correct JSON with online JSON validators.

This strongly points to a bug in `rjson::fromJSON`. You may want to use the RJSONIO package instead for now.

Unfortunately these Instagram replies are quite large. I'll see if I can strip down the JSON output to something manageable so I can post details here. (I'm trying to avoid having to link to data on an external site.)

I suspect an encoding issue with Instagram user names.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.  I tried the same code with RJSONIO instead of RJSON and got this error msg: Error in fromJSON(content, handler, default.size, depth, allowComments,  : 
  invalid JSON input   Could you please tell my how to modify my fromJSON string to work with RJSONIO?

Comment: @SteveF What is the precise `RJSONIO::fromJSON` command that you run which gives that error?

Comment: This is the exact line of code:        media <- fromJSON(getURL(paste(nexturl,token,sep="")),unexpected.escape = "skip")

Comment: Can confirm that "This strongly points to a bug in rjson::fromJSON. You may want to use the RJSONIO package instead for now."

Answer (score 0):

Using RJSONSIO and Rcpp, you should be able to get what you want from:

```
media1 <- fromJSON(getURL(paste(url,token,sep="")
next_url <- media1$pagination[1]
media2 <- fromJSON(getURL(next_url))
```

No need to specify additional arguments in fromJSON()