# Why do I not get the expected list returned by this for loop?

Tags: json, r, for-loop, dataframe

I have a small JSON object

```
j <- list(data= list(c(1489363200000, 186841676082516), c(1489449600000, 186318018993681
    ), c(1489536000000, 195610680688542), c(1489622400000, 197567887268771  
    ), c(1489708800000, 200901384171685), c(1489795200000, 138710699233524
    ), c(1489881600000, 122137578497247), c(1489968000000, 187609138951695
    ), c(1490054400000, 221990103719893), c(1490140800000, 237679711895307
    ), c(1490227200000, 203517279876234), c(1490313600000, 197617683034249
    ), c(1490400000000, 130778992561863), c(1490486400000, 122840062298549
    ), c(1490572800000, 194332605707575), c(1490659200000, 198901100827757
    ), c(1490745600000, 200128701898347), c(1490832000000, 222814133876696
    ), c(1490918400000, 210223087952673), c(1491004800000, 305686669170214
    ), c(1491091200000, 288755720186627), c(1491177600000, 286806683689669
    ), c(1491264000000, 216426591598647), c(1491350400000, 272193687564242
    ), c(1491436800000, 233995158271699), c(1491523200000, 216390247091183
    ), c(1491609600000, 228342701035144), c(1491696000000, 183517184406659
    ), c(1491782400000, 224070387545431), c(1491868800000, 206737520263679
    ), c(1491955200000, 30417143436121)),
 time = structure(list(start = 1489363200000, startTime = "2017-03-13T00:00:00.00Z", 
    end = 1492041600000, endTime = "2017-04-13T00:00:00.00Z", 
    interval = "1 DAY"), .Names = c("start", "startTime", "end", 
"endTime", "interval"))
)
```

That I am trying to store as part of a `data.frame` like so:

```
df_2 <- data.frame(
        Date = seq.Date(as.Date(j$time$startTime), as.Date(j$time$endTime), by = 'days', origin = '1970-01-01'),
        Metric = for (i in seq_along(j$data)) print(j$data[[i]][2])
      )
```

Which throws a mismatched row number (`arguments imply differing number of rows: 32, 0`).

The `Metric` column in question looks like this when I run it outside the call to `data.frame`:

```
  > x <- for (i in seq_along(j$data)) print(j$data[[i]][2])
    [1] 186841676082516
    [1] 186318018993681
    [1] 195610680688542
    [1] 197567887268771
    [1] 200901384171685
    [1] 138710699233524
    [1] 122137578497247
    [1] 187609138951695
    [1] 221990103719893
    [1] 237679711895307
    [1] 203517279876234
    [1] 197617683034249
    [1] 130778992561863
    [1] 122840062298549
    [1] 194332605707575
    [1] 198901100827757
    [1] 200128701898347
    [1] 222814133876696
    [1] 210223087952673
    [1] 305686669170214
    [1] 288755720186627
    [1] 286806683689669
    [1] 216426591598647
    [1] 272193687564242
    [1] 233995158271699
    [1] 216390247091183
    [1] 228342701035144
    [1] 183517184406659
    [1] 224070387545431
    [1] 206737520263679
    [1] 30417143436121
    > x
    NULL
    >
```

What am I overlooking in the construction of the list within the call to `data.frame`? I have a suspicion that the long index of `[1]`s is a clue, and using `return(...)` instead of `print(...)` didn't work)...

Comment: A `for` loop never returns a value. Try `Metric = sapply(j$data, \`[\`, 2)`

Comment: Interesting @MrFlick: picks up all but the last value: `arguments imply differing number of rows: 32, 31`

Comment: Sounds like your `seq.Date` is probably off. It would help if your data were [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). it looks like your `dput()` was cutoff which basically makes it useless.

Comment: How's that @MrFlick

Comment: (also, `as.Date(...)-1` on the `end` fixed it up)

Comment: @MrFlick others on here have told me explicitly to use `dput()` (in fact where I learned the function)... which is the standard?

Comment: You should use `dput()` to create an object that can be copy/pasted into R. Often that means not showing the `dput()` call itself but prefixing the output with the variable name. Actually, the results of `dump()`  are even more useful: `dump("j","")`

Comment: Awesome thank you! @MrFlick

Comment: your `j` is not JSON; how did you create `j` in the first place (there may be better ways to create your `data.frame` from the actual JSON that you had before you created `j` )

Comment: @SymbolixAU `RJSONIO::fromJSON(sprintf('URL/path/%s', met))` where met is `for (met in metrics)` and `metrics` is a list of metrics.

Comment: From my experience `jsonlite::fromJSON(url)` is usually better

Comment: like this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789253/unexpected-character-json-error-in-r) it wasn't able to parse the object returned by my API @SymbolixAU

Comment: `library(tidyverse); j %>% map_at('data', list) %>% flatten() %>% as_data_frame()`?